# Get the next td that has inputs

Tags: jquery

I have many tables this applies to, but here's an example:

```
Cars
 VIN   | Price  | Color  | Financing | Year | Action
=======+========+========+===========+======+========
 1234  | ______ | Blue   | _________ | 2012 | Submit
-------+--------+--------+-----------+------+--------
 2233  | ______ | Red    | _________ | 2016 | Submit
```

The blanks are inputs (`<input type="text">`) and the table represents a normal html table. The `Submit`s are buttons that should also count as inputs.

### Given an index of a td within a tr, I need to return the next td that has inputs.

So if the starting index is `0` aka `$(tr).find('td').eq(0)`, I need `1` or the `$(td)`. If the starting index is `2`, I need `3`. I was previously doing this with a recursive function, but it was giving some weird results.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk7txgwh/).

Comment: So what is index?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *the table represents a normal html table.*  Please show the code then

Comment: _I need 1 or the $(td)_ this part is the must confusing for me

Comment: The starting index is the index of the td within the tr. So each `tr` has 6 `td`s and their indexes are 0-5. So If I send `0` (referring to the first td) I need to get the index of the next td that has an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filter

```js
function getIndex(usedIndex) {
  var $tds = $('tr:first-child td');                                        // only need to get first row if all the same layout

  var $td = $tds.filter(function() {
    var $thisTd = $(this);
    return $tds.index($thisTd) > usedIndex && $thisTd.find('.textbox').length; // filter for if the td index is higher than the entered one and it has a input as a child
  }).eq(0);                                                                 // get the first one
  
  return  $tds.index($td);
}

console.log(getIndex(1))
console.log(getIndex(4))
```

```css
td.red input {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="test" class="textbox"></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="test1" class="textbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="test3" class="textbox"></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="test4" class="textbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I was able to simplify the filter a little bit `... .filter((i,v) => i > usedIndex && $(v).find('input').length)`

Comment: haha, I always forget about the arguments passed into the callback!